# function returning a <li> to DOM

Tags: javascript

This function displays a string to the li in DOM. I'm just not sure how returning a li inside a function works. Thanks!

```
function displayMatches() {
  const wordMatch = findMatches(this.value, cities);
  const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
  const html = wordMatch.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(this.value,'gi');
    const cityName = place.city.replace(regex,`<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    const province = place.admin_name.replace(regex,`<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
```

return `<li>  <span class="name">${cityName}, ${place.admin_name}</span> <span class="population">${formatted.format(place.population)}</span> </li>` ;

```
  }).join('');
  suggestions.innerHTML =html;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please give us your whole javascript, this seems to be missing some bits, like for example the beginning of the function in which this return is. If other code in the function is not relevant, it's best to leave it out, but we need to see a minimal code that is actually running.

Comment: It's not returning `LI` to the `DOM` it's just returning a `string` which is then converted to the `DOM element`. you can read about `DOM APIs`

Comment: You indeed also might want to be more detailed on what exactly you don't undertand...

Comment: Thank you for your advices @LaurentS. sorry new to this platform and figuring things out 

Comment: Thanks @kunalpanchal. I know have some idea how this works but will dive into this much further.